# Is “The One Ring” suitable as an introductory game?

Tags: new-players, the-one-ring

Some of my friends want to play *The One Ring* RPG, but they have never played an RPG before. If any of you have experience using *The One Ring* as a vehicle for introducing people to roleplaying games, did you feel the game was suitable as a first RPG?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE, Nathan. Unfortunately, it's a bit hard for us to answer this question without knowing more about your friends; All we can offer as-is is opinions and speculation, and neither will really help you out. If you could tell us more about your friends, or explained why you're concerned this RPG might be too hard for beginners, we might be in a better position to help.